# Reduce Jenkinsfile's levels of indentation

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use Jenkins scripted pipeline for our project.
But I found that there are many indentation that makes to code ugly.

For example:

```java
throttle('xxx') {
  node('yyy') {
    try {
      stage('build') {
        withEnv(['aaa=bbb']) {
          if (foo == bar) {
            dir('/my/dir') {
               echo 'Building project'
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The level of indentation becomes even deeper if I use more if or closure or other statements. Is there any way to reduce it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As in other languages, if the indentation level becomes too deep, try to extract
some code as functions.

For the example, I can extract the build stage as a function:

```java
throttle('xxx') {
  node('yyy') {
    try {
      stage('build') {
        build()
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ...
    }
  }
}

def build() {
  withEnv(['aaa=bbb']) {
    if (foo == bar) {
      dir('/my/dir') {
        echo 'Building project'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Declarative Pipeline syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-pipeline). Im my opinion it is far better readable and way less ugly. Here is a try to

```
pipline {
    agent any

    envrionment {
        aaa = "bbb"
    }

    stage("build") {
        when { expression { foo == bar } }
        steps {
            throttle('xxx') {
                dir('/my/dir') {
                    echo 'Building project'
                }
            }
        }
        post {
            failure {
                //...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I must admit it is still quite a lot of indentation.

Comment: I have tried declarative pipeline, but there are some functions that aren't provided in standard steps. For example, I want to do string manipulation or use loops to execute stages base on parameters. I can use script step to run groovy codes but it's becomes messy (and another indentation...)
So eventually I gave up declarative and write everything in scripted syntax.

Comment: @HsuHau you can use custom step definition to put some of the more complex scripts (see https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).

Comment: Thanks for that advice. Currently we do have some functions in var/utils.groovy to share between jobs. I also think that comparing with Scripted syntax, Declarative syntax is neater. Actually most of our jobs use Declarative syntax since it is easier to write and maintain. Scripted pipeline is used only for those jobs containing complex operations.